# Do we need to use MVC Model DataAnnotation if no validations or Code First Approach are used?

Tags: model-view-controller, data-annotations

There might be a similar question already or phrased a little bit differently, but I was just wondering if there any valid reasons to use Data Annotations in MVC Models rather then for Model Validations and Code First approach?

The reason I'm asking is that I have a Report page that will never be used for editing, validations and Code First approach

I have created a `ReportViewModel` where I declared my ReportModels that represent different sections of the report.

I also have a Server Entity that maps the values to the particular Report Model and then the Report Models' properties gets mapped to the view.

Does that make any sense to use DataAnnotations with Report Models at all, if I do not use any editing logic with my report?

Can I just declare properties on my `ReportViewModel` and map Server Entity data directly to those properties without using Report Models?

Comment: `DisplayFormat` attributes would be useful if you using `DisplayFor()` in the view

Comment: But, I can build format template for the same purpose as well. Right?